# failed to download Transformers

Tags: nlp, model, bert-language-model

To update pip, run:pip install--upgrade pipand then retry package installation.If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain. [end of output]note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.ERROR: Failed building wheel for safetensorsSuccessfully built pyyamlFailed to build tokenizers safetensors ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, safetensors, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Padahal versi PIP saya adalah 23.2.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.